# Group Events - access permissions & graph API

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-group

I'm having issues obtaining event data for a group in Facebook.  I'm using an application access key to authenticate access.

The questions I have are:

1. Graph API doesn't seem to have Group Event data included as part of their FQL.  Does this mean that this data is not intended to be pulled.
2. I tried alternatively pulling by the group owner:  `FROM event WHERE eid IN (SELECT eid FROM event_member WHERE uid='.''.')`, but the access permissions are not correct.  Does this mean I need a user key or if they "authorize app" will that be good enough? (and how can I find the screen for them to auth app)?